# Place an HTML textbox on an image in a fixed position for both desktop and mobile site

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a textbox on top of an image (treasure chest) and I want the textbox to stay intact in a fixed position right about the slate on the treasure chest. (image attached)

[image]

It looks perfect in the desktop, but in mobile the text box comes a little lower than the slate as shown in picture. How can i make it stick in the same position on mobile too? (pic attached)[image]

```
    <img src="img/Shadow_plate2x.png" style="position:relative; width:75%;height:75%"><br>
    <input type="number" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        type = "number"
        maxlength = "5"  id="PlayerAnswer24" align="middle"  name="PlayerAnswerx" required="required" style="background-color: transparent;
position:absolute;
top: 31%;
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
letter-spacing: 22px; 
color:white; 
padding-left:30px; border:0px" placeholder="XXXXX"  autocomplete="off"/>
```

This is the code which I have. Please help. TIA. (Pardon me for my rookie mistakes)

Comment: Can you include the full URL for the treasure chest image, or upload it to imgur and share that link please?

Comment: Sure, Here's the link: https://imgur.com/1McVPJe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `img` element can't have children we encase it with a `div` and expand it to fill the parent, Now the div and the `img` have the same dimensions which means we can align an input within the `div` and it'll be aligned with the `img` as well.

Used percentage values to keep it dynamic with the width.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  /* remove unwanted space below the image*/
  font-size: 0;
  /* to resize bottom right corner */
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  /* starting point*/
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 9%;
  width: 54%;
  top: 36%;
  left: 22%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  /* red to show up */
  background-color: red;
  letter-spacing: 22px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1McVPJe.png">
  <input type="number" placeholder="XXXXX" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for for mobile view, but this HTML/CSS is a simpler way to set things up, and you should be able to tweak it more easily:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("PlayerAnswer24");
input.oninput = function() {
  if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#chest {
  max-width: 100%
}

#PlayerAnswer24 {
  position: absolute;
  letter-spacing: 22px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: 0px;
  top: 37%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="chest" src="https://i.imgur.com/1McVPJe.png"><br>
  <input type="number" type="number" maxlength="5" id="PlayerAnswer24" name="PlayerAnswerx" required="required" placeholder="XXXXX" autocomplete="off" />
  <div>
```